# Using TRUNCATE TABLE on JavaDB

Tags: java, sql, javadb

I'm getting this error on using `TRUNCATE TABLE` statement in Java:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Operation 'TRUNCATE TABLE'
cannot be performed on object 'PULLOUT' because there 
is an open ResultSet dependent on that object.
```

This is my Java code:

```
try {
 dataManager.setStatement(dataManager.getConnection().
                createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, 
                ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE));
 dataManager.getStatement().executeUpdate("truncate table EJP.CUSTOMER");
 refreshCustomerTransactionTable();
} 
catch (SQLException ex) 
{
 Logger.getLogger(MainForm.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
```

Comment: **because there is an open ResultSet** copied from ur stack trace

Comment: The error message seems pretty obvious to me